# How to make about us slider responsive to mobile and lower resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i made about us slider with three persons and how do i make it responsive that it resize based on resolution, i tried @media and other stuff but it isnt working
Thanks
html code:

```
<section class="hidden">
        <div class="glowny">
          <div class="conteiner-onas">
            <div class="testimonial swiper mySwiper">
              <div class="slide-row swiper-wrapper" id="slide">
                <div class="slide-col swiper-slide">
                  <div class="user-text">
                    <p>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,


                    </p>
                    <h3>xyz</h3>
                    <p>xxx</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-img">
                    <img src="#" alt="photo1" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-col swiper-slide">
                  <div class="user-text">
                    <p>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,


                    </p>
                    <h3>xyz</h3>
                    <p>xxx</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-img">
                    <img src="#" alt="photo2" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-col swiper-slide">
                  <div class="user-text">
                    <p>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,


                    </p>
                    <h3>xyz</h3>
                    <p>xxx</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-img">
                    <img src="#" alt="photo" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-btn"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-btn"></div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- Swiper JS -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
      <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 25,
          loop: true,
          centerSlide: "true",
          grabCursor: "true",

          navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
          },
          pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            clickable: true,
          },
        });
      </script>
```

css code

```
.glowny {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.glowny h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.glowny1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.glowny1 h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.slide-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
.slide-col {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  position: relative;
}
.user-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.user-img img {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.user-text {
  background: #2d3a59;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #d3d4d6;
  padding: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}

.user-text p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.user-text h3 {
  margin: 35px 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.conteiner-onas {
  width: 1250px;
  height: 625px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -50px;
}


.active {
  width: 40px;
}

.testimonial {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thank you so much im stuck there

i tried media screen and some chat gpt responsive answers but none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

just a little change

```
.conteiner-onas {
  width: 100%;  /* changed from 1250px to 100%*/
  height: 625px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Still isnt working :/